# How can I distinguish phone from tablet

Tags: android, air

Using Adobe AIR for Android, I'd like to find a way to distinguish a phone from a tablet. The closest I can find is detecting the dpi. (My phone dpi is 254, my tablet is 149) but is that going to be reliable or is there a better way?

(I've been using stackoverflow for a while but this is my first post - yippee!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but is that going to be reliable

Absolutely not. A T-Mobile G1 would be a tablet by that measure.

> is there a better way?

Frankly, you should not be caring whether an Android device is a telephone, tablet, television, toaster, telescope, or toilet.

You *should* be caring about characteristics and capabilities.

For example, if you are thinking about tablets in terms of screen size, use `<supports-screens>` and the `-large` and `-xlarge` resource sets (e.g., `res/layout/` for normal stuff and `res/layout-large/` for larger screen sizes).

Or, if you are thinking about tablets in terms of whether or not you can place a phone call, use `<uses-feature>` and `hasSystemFeature()` on `PackageManager`.

Comment: I'm using Adobe AIR for Android, I don't have access to those attributes. If I were writing a native Android application I could do this.

The reason I'm concerned is I want to allow the tablet version to rotate but not the phone. I need an on-screen status bar and on a phone in landscape it's taking too much real estate and makes the playing area too small.

Comment: @cdotspace: If Adobe AIR does not have ways for you to detect and react to screen size, then Adobe AIR is not ready for prime time. Bear in mind that if you know density and you know resolution, then you know size -- resolution / density = size.

Comment: AIR does have the ability to detect and react to screen size, the question is that a reliable test for a tablet? It sounds like you're saying 'yes'.

I would agree that Flash isn't ready for prime-time yet but after using my Xoom for a week I would say the same about the current Android tablets available.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a device is a tablet or not could mean...

One.... Is it running the Honeycomb tablet version (Android 3.0) ? You can use System.getProperty() to get this information.

or

Two....Is it tablet sized? i.e. is the screen a larger size? But bear in mind some tablets are not that big. Best way to handle these is separate resources for each device size.

I'd say in general it's a bad idea to try to define Android tablets into specific groups, as there are many varieties now and a LOT more are coming. So usually best to build your app so it handles different screen sizes, different OS versions, and different features being available or absent (e.g. GPS, keyboard etc).

Comment: The application I'm building does use a fluid layout (it's actually one source code for Mac/Win desktop, iOS/Android phone/tablet, and web) it's just that the main content area gets too small on a phone in landscape. I've decided to just let the user decide, they can rotate back to portrait if they don't like it. (Apple will most likely reject it but I don't really care about iPhones).

Answer (score 0):

cdotspace, don't worry about the real dpi, you only need to get virutal dpi:

```
int virtual_dpi=webview1.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
```

Virutal dpi means dots per virtual inch.
For example, the htc desire hd's real width is 2.21 inches, but its virutal width is still 2 inches, the galaxy tab 10.1's real width is 5.35 inches(portrait orient), but its virtual width is 5 inches.

```
int portrait_width_pixel=Math.min(this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
int dots_per_virtual_inch=this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
float virutal_width_inch=portrait_width_pixel/dots_per_virtual_inch;
if (virutal_width_inch<=2)
   {//is phone
   }
else
    {//is tablet
    }
```